# How do I use a property to initialize another property?

Tags: c#, constructor, properties, roslyn, c#-6.0

Why is this:

```
public int X { get; } = 5
public int Y { get; } = X;
```

not possible?

Because doing it manually:

```
public TestClass()
{
  X = 5;
  Y = X;
}
```

Works, and so does (obviously?) this:

```
public static int X { get; } = 5;
public static int Y { get; } = X;
```

Is there a way to get the first example to compile, or do I have to do it manually in the ctor?

*(My real problem is far more complex, not just ints, but instances that are then being used to create other instances, but this example is easier to discuss)*

Comment: "Because that's what the C# spec says" is the unfortunate answer "... it is a compile-time error to reference `this` in a variable initializer, as it is a compile-time error for a variable initializer to reference any instance member through a simple-name"

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks, whats a simple-name?

Comment: A simple name is basically reference to a member without explicitly saying `this.` before it. E.g. you're using a simple name to reference the `X` member in the second line of your first example.

Comment: [10.4.5.2 Instance field initialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645759(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Does it necessarily have to be readonly properties backed by a field? One could argue that `Y` could be defined to just return the value of `X`.  You don't necessarily need storage for it.

Comment: @JeffMercado if I have a more complex scenario where I need X to instantiate a class? Then it wont work anymore. I just used that example for ez discussion/example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why this is not possible is that these initializations are done *before* the constructor is called. So it happens in a **static** context. The object is not yet fully initialized and there is no `this` reference yet. So you cannot access a *non-static* property like `X`.

For the same reason it works for the *static* properties in your third example.

So I don't see a workaround but doing this kind of initialization in a constructor.

Comment: "these initializations are done before the constructor is called" Not true. They are incorporated in the constructor as far as I know.

Comment: @PatrickHofman they are done before everything else in the constructor logic. The first thing done when constructing an object is reserving the memory for the object, then the initialization is done and then the constructor logic is executed.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I guess you are right regarding the code generated by the compiler, but from the developer's point of view it is _before_ the constructor, at least before `this` is available, but `this` can be accessed in a constructor.

Comment: "Before anything else" isn't that much different than the other approach @Adwaenyth

Comment: Properties X and Y are members of TestClass. "The second example is totally off topic because it is simply syntactic sugar for" makes no sense then, its meant to be a ctor for the class, where the properties are members from

Comment: @Mafi sorry, misunderstood that second example then, took it for an object initializer.

Comment: @PatrickHofman it's just about how the constructor actually can be handled logically. You need to have the memory reserved first, because otherwise you can't store any data in the object. Then again the properties need to be initialized before the constructor logic because you must be able to access the properties reliably in the constructor.

Comment: @Adwaenyth it seems like it could be possible, but there are too many edge cases, so they decided to not allow it by defining that in the specification. The autoproperty initialization gets done before the calls to the base ctor's so this could cause problems, too.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the value of a non-static property `X` in an initializer expression of property `Y` for the same reason that you cannot use the value of a non-static field `x` in an initializer expression of field `y`, i.e.

```
public int x = 5;
public int y = x; // Not allowed
```

This triggers [error CS0236](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5724t6za.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), because compiler is allowed to decide on the order in which it processes field and property initializers for partial classes. Although `X` is guaranteed to be initialized ahead of `Y` when both properties are defined in the same file, there is no such guarantee for properties defined in different files containing the code of a partial class.

Compiler designers could implement it differently by allowing initializers to reference other fields and properties defined before the field or property being initialized, but the feature is not worth the trouble, because you can easily work around it by moving intialization into the constructor.

Doing the same inside a constructor does not present a problem, because you are in control of the order of assignments. When you say in the constructor that `X` must be initialized before `Y`, the compiler is not allowed to change that order.

Comment: Indeed. I think the only real reason is order of execution. When you write a constructor by hand, you can force when what is called. If we let the compiler or CLR do that, we can get unexpected and non-deterministic behavior.

Comment: "compiler is allowed to change the order in which it processes field and property initializers" - no it isn't. According to the C# spec, they're processed in textual order.

Comment: (C# Spec, Version 5, Section 10.5.5.2): "The variable initializers are executed in the textual order in which they appear in the class declaration. "

Comment: But it is possible to call a variable that isn't initialized yet. This might cause problems. If you don't allow that, you 'fix' that problem.

Comment: "they're processed in textual order." - I can support that. R# warns me, if I use 2 static properties, and the first one assigns itself the value of the second one with the property initializer.

Comment: (Re: your edit to partial classes. Whilst it is true that I cannot find a rule in the C# spec regarding how textual order is defined for partial classes, based on a quick read, it should be noted that this prohibition predates partial classes)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would do it:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public int X { get; set; } = 5;
    public int Y => X;
}
```

Better way for auto properties based of other properties:
public class TestClass
{
public int X { get; set; } = 5;
public int Y
{
get
{
var y = X;
return y;
}
}
}

Comment: this is not the same. Y is a computed property in your case. This works, but it is not exactly the same.

Answer (score -1):

This is mostly possible now with the advent of primary constructors in C# 12 (which are similar to F#'s primary constructors).

```cs
public class TestClass(int x)
{
    public int X { get; } = x;
    public int Y { get; } = x;
    
    public TestClass() : this(5) { }
}
```

This works out great, provided that you're okay with exposing an additional public `TestClass(int x)` constructor. If there were a way to make that constructor `private`, this would provide *precisely* what you're looking for.

---

Perhaps in a future language version, the designers will allow this, too: they specifically acknowledges this potential extension in the feature proposal (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-12.0/primary-constructors#drawbacks; specifically the last bullet point in the "Drawbacks" section).